# Rebuilding Old Gaming Computer, System Cloning ?'s

Tags: upgrade, games, hardware, clonezilla

Basically building a new gaming desktop and want to clone my current system setup. **Re-using:** disk drive (current and future media disk); **New:** SSD for OS and applications, processor, graphics card,tower, power supply.

Was planning to use Clonezilla to clone my existing 120gb SSD to a new 2tb PCIe SSD that will house the OS and all the applications. My existing media [disk] drive will continue to hold my media (music, movies, photos, documents, etc.). My assumption is that since I'm upgrading basically everything, I'm going to have a bit of a hassle getting all the directory paths sorted so all roads point to where they're supposed to.

Am I going about this wrong? Is there an easier way? Or am I on the right track, yet there's a specific sequence I should follow? This is new territory for me, I'm still quite the linux amateur, even though I've been using Ubuntu for over a decade...

Running Ubuntu 22.04.2

Comment: I would - and have - used your approach. I would not expect any directory related problems. Assuming the PCs are both UEFI, you will probably have to run boot-repair to get it to boot the first time, since the NVRAM variables won't be set.